Solving Difference Equation from Feller's
I'm trying to derive the closed solution for $a_n : 0<n<m$, $$a_n = 1 + \frac{a_{n+1}} 2 + \frac{a_{n-1}}2,\ \ \ \ a_0= a_m = 0$$
Basically, it's the hitting time for a simple random walk. A similar (generalized) problem seems to feature in Feller's probability theory. In it, he converts it to a homogeneous difference equation (difference of two solutions) and says that $-n^2$ is a solution, leading to $-n^2+A+Bn$. I have no clue how he found $-n^2$ or the subsequent form. Is this just just some ansatz for difference equations of this form?
For an arbitrary $a_n$, the solution is $a_n = n(m-n)$. Can anyone help me figure out how to directly show this closed form?

The second differences $a_{n+1} - 2a_n + a_{n-1}$ are constant, which indicates a quadratic function.

Sorry. I'll fix those indices. So is it just an ansatz then? There's no direct way to show this?

There's a nice probabilistic solution as well. Let $\tau$ be the time to hit either $0$ or $n$, and let $X_t$, $t=0,1,2,\dots$, be the position of the simple random walk. Your function of interest is
$$
a_m=\mathbb{E}(\tau\mid X_0=m).
$$
Let $Y_t=X_t^2-t$, then $Y_t$ is a martingale with respect to filtration generated by the walk, as well as $X_t$ itself, as
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_{t+1}\mid X_t)=\frac12\left[X_t+1\right]+\frac12\left[X_t-1\right]=X_t,
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y_{t+1}\mid X_t)=\frac12\left[(X_t+1)^2-(t+1)\right]+\frac12\left[(X_t-1)^2-(t+1)\right]=X_t^2-t=Y_t.
$$
Let $\mathbb{P}(X_\tau=n)=:p$, then $\mathbb{P}(X_\tau=0)=1-p$.
By optional stopping theorem
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_\tau)=X_0=m,\quad \mathbb{E}(Y_\tau)=Y_0=m^2
$$
and at the same time $\mathbb{E}(X_\tau)=p\cdot n+(1-p)\cdot 0$ so $p=m/n$, and also
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y_\tau)=\mathbb{E}(X_\tau^2-\tau)=p\cdot n^2 +(1-p)\cdot 0^2-\mathbb{E}(\tau)
$$
i.e.
$$
m^2=\frac{m}n\cdot n^2-\mathbb{E}(\tau)
$$
yielding $\mathbb{E}(\tau)=mn-m^2$.

This is perfect!

The second differences are constant:
$$
(a_{n+1} - a_n) - (a_n -a_{n-1}) = a_{n+1} - 2a_n + a_{n-1} = -2 \, .
$$
It follows that the first differences are a linear function of $n$:
$$
 a_{n+1} - a_n = -2n + A
$$
with some constant $A$, which in turn implies that $a_n$ is a quadratic function of $n$:
$$
 a_n = -n^2 + Bn + C
$$
with some constants $B, C$. The unique quadratic function with leading term $-n^2$ which satisfies the boundary conditions $a_0 = a_m = 0$ is
$$
  a_n = n (m-n) \, .
$$
